# 2 filters in one on reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

i am having this trouble i hae made 2 diferent filters
one that filters for selected categorys and another one that filters by date on a datepicker
but i needthem to be in one for this cases
1.- You want to filter only by category selected
2.- You want to filter only by date
3.- You want to filter by category and date selected

the way i filter by category is this one and it works

```
filterData = (data) =>{
return data.filter((value,index)=>{
  if (this.state.filterSelected.indexOf(value.category)>-1) {
        return(value)
      }
})
```

}

and the griddle looks like this

```
<Griddle
data={this.state.filterSelected.length === 0  ? data : this.filterData(data)}
pageProperties={{
  pageSize: 100,
}}
plugins={[plugins.LocalPlugin]}
components={this.state.filterOptions}
```

/>

the way i filter by date looks like this and it works too

```
 filterData = (data) =>{
  return data.filter((value,index)=>{
   if (this.state.dateSelected === value.time) {
      return(value)
    }
  })
}
```

and the griddle looks like this

```
    <Griddle
    data={this.state.dateSelected ==='' ? data : this.filterData(data)}
    pageProperties={{
      pageSize: 100,
    }}
    plugins={[plugins.LocalPlugin]}
    components={this.state.filterOptions}
  />
```

both of them works separated, and i know its more a logic problem than anything i hae come to this solution for the filter data 
but i dont know how to pass the valors on griddle, i would apreciate a little help

```
  filterData = (data) =>{
    return data.filter((value,index)=>{
     if (
          (this.state.filterSelected.length>0 && 
          this.state.filterSelected.indexOf(value.category)>-1 && 
          this.state.dateSelected !='' && this.state.dateSelected(value.time)>-1)||
          (this.state.filterSelected.length==0 && 
          this.state.dateSelected !='' && this.state.dateSelected(value.time)) ||
          (this.state.filterSelected.length>0 && 
          this.state.filterSelected.indexOf(value.category) && 
          this.state.dateSelected =='')
         ){
        return(value)
      }
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your render set a variable equal to all data then add two filters. for example:

```
render() {
  let filteredData = data;
  if (filterByDate) filteredData = this.filterByCategory(filteredData);
  if (filterByCategory) filteredData = this.filterByCategory(filteredData);

  return (
    <Griddle
      data={filteredData.length === 0 ? data : filteredData}
      pageProperties={{
        pageSize: 100,
      }}
      plugins={[plugins.LocalPlugin]}
      components={this.state.filterOptions}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: i think that i dont understood, i did this, but since i cant make filters on the render i throws me a syntax error

Comment: @user8485597 My example was mostly sudo code. You should user your functions that you wrote and return the filtered data from them.

Comment: Create two different filter Data functions. One for category one for Date. Then return the filtered data from them. Does that make sense?

Comment: i tried your example but i didnt got it at all, it still throw me an error and was to shy to keep bothering you, but i already solved the problem, thanks for your time